# Using a textbox and two pulldowns to search and filter MySql results on a PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

I have a page that has a textbox which is attached to a MySql database, it is used to search on records of people using their Surname.

To make the page more useful, I have added 2 pulldown menus. One menu is for a location of a memorial, the other is for a conflict such as World War I, World War II, etc. I would like to use the pulldown menus as filters for the search results.

The pulldown menus would need to work with the textbox and also independently, giving results on the records as:

- Surname
- Surname + Memorial
- Surname + Conflict
- Memorial
- Memorial + Conflict
- Conflict

The code I have for the form is:

```
<div class="memorialphp">
    <form action='./memorial.php' method='get'>

        <!-- $surname or 'surname' -->
        <input type='text' name='term' placeholder="Search...">

        <!-- $memorial or 'memorial' -->
        <select name="memorialsearch">
            <option value=" ">All Memorials</option>
            <option value="Hinckley War Memorial">Hinckley War Memorial</option>
            <option value="Burbage War Memorial">Burbage War Memorial</option>
            <option value="Barwell War Memorial">Barwell War Memorial</option>
            <option value="Earl Shilton War Memorial">Earl Shilton War Memorial</option>
        </select>

        <!-- $conflictsort or 'conflictsort' -->
        <select name="confictsearch">
            <option value="">All Conflicts</option>
            <option value="1">World War I</option>
            <option value="2">World War II</option>
            <option value="3">20th Century Wars</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

The code I have for the PHP is:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) {
        $term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);     
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE surname LIKE '%".$term."%' ORDER BY surname, fullname, conflictsort"; 
        $r_query = mysql_query($sql);

        if(mysql_num_rows($r_query)){
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){
                $id = $row['id'];
                $initial = $row['initial'];
                $surname = $row['surname'];
                $fullname = $row['fullname'];
                $dob = $row['dob'];
                $born = $row['born'];
                $service = $row['service'];
                $enlisteddate = $row['enlisteddate'];
                $enlisted = $row['enlisted'];
                $number = $row['number'];
                $rank = $row['rank'];
                $batt = $row['batt'];
                $unit = $row['unit'];
                $section = $row['section'];
                $died = $row['died'];
                $death = $row['death'];
                $memorial = $row['memorial'];
                $conflict = $row['conflict'];
                $conflictsort = $row['conflictsort'];
                $biography = $row['biography'];
                $link = $row['link'];

                echo"<h4>$surname</h4>
                <b>Name:</b> $fullname - <b>Rank:</b> $rank ($number) - <b>Regiment:</b> $batt $unit $section
                <br /><b>Birth:</b> $dob $born
                <br /><b>Enlisted:</b> $service - $enlisteddate $enlisted
                <br /><b>Died:</b> $died $death
                <br /><b>Memorial:</b> Shown as $initial$surname at $memorial
                <br /><b>Confilct:</b> $conflict
                <br /><b><a href='$link'>$biography</a></b>
                <br /><br /><br />";
            } 
        }else{
            echo "<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><p><b>No records, please try again...</b></p>";
        } 
    }
?>
```

Please be aware that I am a total beginner, the ideal solution would be for you to change the code and post up explaining how and what has been changed to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

First thing: do always use the `mysqli` module, never the old and deprecated `mysql`.

This is how to open the connection to the database using `mysqli`:

```
$db=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassw,$dbname);
```

Ok, now we're ready for the search part. 
I would use a variable called `$where`, where to store the *where* clause of your query. This clause will be composed dynamically depending on the user input. Something like:

```
$where='';

if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) {
    $term=$db->escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);
    $where.=" AND surname LIKE '%$term%'";
}
if (!empty($_REQUEST['memorialsearch'])) {
    $memorial=$db->escape_string($_REQUEST['memorialsearch']);
    $where.=" AND memorial='$memorial'";
}
if (!empty($_REQUEST['conflictsearch'])) {
    $conflict=$db->escape_string($_REQUEST['conflictsearch']);
    $where.=" AND conflict='$conflict'";
}
```

I don't know the exact structure of your `search` table, so it is possible you will have to adapt the above code to match your actual field names.

At the end of this block, if there was some search field in the request, `$where` will not be empty. Also notice that a non empty `$where` will always begin with " AND". This makes it simpler to compose the clause dynamically, but requires a first condition our `$where` can be appended to.

So this is how we proceed:

```
if ($where) {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM search WHERE 1".$where;
    $r_query = $db->query($sql);

    // generate the output
}
```

The "1" in the query is an always true condition to which we can append our `$where` and be syntactically correct.

The output part should still be fine, I suppose.

Comment: Thank you for helping @xzoert

Do I have to keep mysqli_num_rows

[code]
if ($where) {
 $sql="SELECT * FROM search WHERE 1".$where;
 $r_query = $db->query($sql);
    
if(mysqli_num_rows($r_query)){
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_query)){
  $id = $row['id'];
[/code]

Comment: Sorry for the message being messy, I can't lay the code out as it looks.

Comment: Yes, the code after the query should be the same you already have (except for using mysqli_xxx in place of mysql_xxx).

Comment: You can pass the database name directly as fourth parameter to mysqli_connect (skipping the mysqli_select_db part). If you get an abject back, you're ok: connection was successful.

Comment: I have been trying to get the code working from above and I am very confused on where it goes and what it replaces. Could you please add the code to the code that I have put above so that I can see what I need to do.